# Capture issue when parsing bad file with Config::General

Tags: perl

I am using perl 5.16.3 and face following problem

I have a code to read a Config::General format file using following code:

```
use Config::General qw(ParseConfig);
my $meta_file = "/foo/bar/file";
my $hash;
eval {
    $hash = {ParseConfig($meta_file)};
};

if ($@) {
    print $@;
}
```

Now when there is a issue in file pointed buy $meta_file, this code fails with stack trace similar to following:

> Use of uninitialized value $n_read in numeric eq (==)
>     Config::General::_openfile_for_read('Config::General=HASH(0xff92e30)',
>   '/foo/bar/file')
>     Config::General::_open('Config::General=HASH(0xff92e30)',
>   '/foo/bar/file')
>     Config::General::_process('Config::General=HASH(0xff92e30)')
>     Config::General::new('Config::General', '/foo/bar/file')

Is there a way to capture this and continue with my code?

Comment: I'm having a surprisingly hard time producing a config file that that library *refuses* to parse. Can you provide an erroneous config file for testing?

Comment: I still don't see how your code `die`s from inside `eval` ... `Carp::Heavy` issues?  There are also some bug reports quoted in the source.  What happens if you add a hook `$SIG{__DIE__} = sub { say "die: @_" }`?  (The "_uninitialized_" warning will still come out, which you can suppress, but that doesn't terminate your program.)  But even if this works you'll still need to find out what is wrong with the file.

Comment: I couldn't find a single word on error handling in the docs ... but by the source it it appears that that their code fails to [read into $n_read](https://metacpan.org/source/TLINDEN/Config-General-2.63/General.pm#L568), where it reads the initial characters from the file to check for BOM. So it is "_uninitialized_" (undefined) on the next line of source. Can your file have something strange at its beginning?  I tried (with an empty file as well) and can't reproduce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in `eval` appears to terminate the program, so a `die` triggered from the initialization code must have escaped. The module uses `Carp::Heavy` for which strange behavior has been reported occasionally and this could be the source of trouble. There are also various bug reports quoted in module's source.

You can attempt to control this with a [hook for `die`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%SIG)

```
$SIG{__DIE__} = sub { say "Got: @_" };
```

but that may or may well not work.

Eventually the question is why this happens. The reported warning (which in itself doesn't terminate the program) can be traced [in the source to](https://metacpan.org/source/TLINDEN/Config-General-2.63/General.pm#L568)

> # attempt to read an initial utf8 byte-order mark (BOM)
>
> ```
> my $n_read  = sysread $fh, my $read_BOM, length(_UTF8_BOM);
> ```

what apparently fails to read since `$n_read` remains undefined ("*uninitialized*") in the next line.  The `undef` return from [sysread](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sysread.html) indicates an error. The constant [`_UTF8_BOM` is defined as](https://metacpan.org/source/TLINDEN/Config-General-2.63/General.pm#L41)

> ```
> use constant _UTF8_BOM => "\x{ef}\x{bb}\x{bf}";
> ```

(Three characters since `:utf8` layer is set only a few lines below `sysread`, conditionally)

So check the first characters of your file. I've tried to confuse `sysread` (one of the guesses being a null byte) but couldn't reproduce the behavior. An empty file worked fine as well.